# Akka 2.2.3 TCP client not reporting ConnectionClosed

Tags: scala, akka

I can connect to a `ServerSocket` using Akka I/O, but when I close the socket I'm not seeing any sort of `ConnectionClosed` message returned.

The first test passes, but the second does not (with both 2.2.3 and 2.3.0-RC2):

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

import java.net._

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.io._
import akka.testkit.TestActorRef

object System {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("SocketListenerTests")
}
import System._

class Listener extends Actor {
  val manager = IO(Tcp)

  private var _last: Any = null
  def last = _last

  def receive = {
    case a: Any => _last = a
  }

  def connect(addr: InetSocketAddress) { manager ! Tcp.Connect(addr) }
}

class AkkaTcpTests extends Specification {
  override def is = args(sequential = true) ^ super.is  

  val socket = new ServerSocket(0)
  val addr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", socket.getLocalPort)

  def pause { Thread.sleep(200) }

  val listener = TestActorRef[Listener].underlyingActor

  "Akka TCP I/O" should {
    "open connections" in {
      listener.connect(addr)
      pause
      listener.last must beAnInstanceOf[Tcp.Connected]
    }
    "notify when server sockets are closed" in {
      socket.close
      pause
      listener.last must beAnInstanceOf[Tcp.ConnectionClosed]
    }
  }
}
```

> [error]    'Connected(localhost/127.0.0.1:59141,/127.0.0.1:54809)' is not an instance of 'akka.io.Tcp$ConnectionClosed' (AkkaTcpTests.scala:46)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/io-tcp.html

Your listener has to register itself with the connection before it receives any further TCP messages:

> In order to activate the new connection a Register message must be
>   sent to the connection actor, informing that one about who shall
>   receive data from the socket. Before this step is done the connection
>   cannot be used, and there is an internal timeout after which the
>   connection actor will shut itself down if no Register message is
>   received.

In the receive block of the listener add a

```
case c @ Connected(remote, local) =>
  val connection = sender
  connection ! Register(self)
  // change behaviour with become, notify someone, ...
```

**Edit:** As Roland pointed out, in the given scenario one also needs to call `accept()` on the `ServerSocket`, which returns a Socket, and call `close()` that one in order to trigger a `PeerClosed` message (which is an `instanceOf[Tcp.ConnectionClosed]`). If you call `close()` on the ServerSocket an error is thrown as you closed the servers connection. But usually you don't have to deal with this level when using Akk IO.

Answer (score 1):

Closing a `ServerSocket` does not terminate connections which were accepted by it, you will have to obtain the `Socket` by calling `accept()` and then you can close that one to tear down the connection.

This is needed in addition to the answer given by Carsten.